# How to graph probability density function when given density function

Tags: function, distribution, probability

I want to graph the pdf and verify the total area under the density curve is 1. I am given that 
f(x) = .075x+.2 when 3 ≤ x ≤ 5    and f(x)=0 otherwise
Can you help me figure out what the code for this question is?

Answer (score 1):

You can plot this function in Mathematica using:

```
Plot[Piecewise[{{0.075 x + 2, 3 <= x && x <= 5}}, 0], {x, 0, 5}]
```

[image: plot of fun]

And then verify area using definite integral (from 0 to infinity):

```
Integrate[Piecewise[{{0.075 x + 0.2, 3 <= x && x <= 5}}, 0], {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

(which results in 1).

You can of course calculate it by hand.

Integral represents area under the curve. When `x` is not in range `[3,5]` then area is always zero.

So your problem can be reduced to calculating integral from `0.075 x + 0.2`, between `3` and `5`.

Integral from `(0.075 x + 0.2)dx` equals to `0.2 x + 0.0375 x^2 + C`. When calculated in range, equals to `1.9375 - 0.9375 = 1`.